# What does pop() return as opposed to return pop()?

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing this HackerRank challenge that involved implementing queue and stack structures, and I ran into some strange behavior regarding the **pop()** function in Python.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-queues-stacks/problem

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.stack = []

    def pushCharacter(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)

    def enqueueCharacter(self, item):
        self.queue.insert(0, item)

    def popCharacter(self):
        return self.stack.pop()

    def dequeueCharacter(self):
        return self.queue.pop()
```

This is my code that works, but if I were to remove the return call from the **popCharacter()** and **dequeueCharacter()** functions and just have **pop()** return the value, it doesn't satisfy the test cases! Doesn't **pop()** explicitly return the last value of an array? What's the difference between that and **return pop()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
def popCharacter(self):
    return self.stack.pop()
```

You are returning what `pop()` returns.  But if you do this:

```
def popCharacter(self):
    self.stack.pop()
```

You are returning `None` every time.  Python isn't Bash, so there's no magic "return whatever the most recent function call returned" feature.  If you want to return something other than `None` you need to actually `return` it.

Comment: Wow that seems like a really intuitive concept but it went right over my head. Thank you for the clarification.